# how to bring errormessages back from class that extends AutoDisposeNotifier

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Since the best practice is to not return anything back from the class that extends `Notifier`, how do I bring back the errors that occur in the methods back to UI? For example, I have a method in my class that signs users up but if there is an error in signing user up, how do I bring it back to UI? Here is how my class look like:

```
String errorMessages = "";

class AuthService extends AutoDisposeNotifier<AppUser?> {
  Future registerUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      {required String email,
      required String password,
      required String username}) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _firebaseAuth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);


      User? user = result.user;

      state = _appUserFromFirebaseUser(user);

    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      // How to bring the error back to UI?
    }
  }
}
```

Here is how I am creating the provider:

```
final authServiceProvider = NotifierProvider.autoDispose<AuthService, AppUser?>(
  () {
    return AuthService();
  },
);
```

Here is how I am calling it from UI:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final localauthserviceprovider = ref.read(authServiceProvider.notifier);
  ... // code removed that returns Scaffold for brevity
  ElevatedButton(
    child: const Text("Register"),
    onPressed: () async {
      if (_formkey.currentState!.validate()) {
        await localauthserviceprovider
                .registerUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: emailController.text,
                password: passwordController.text,
                username: usernameController.text);
        }
      },
    ), 
    const SizedBox(
      height: 12,
    ),
    Text(
      errorMessages,
      style: const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.red,
      fontSize: 14,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
}
```

Comment: There's an example about this: https://riverpod.dev/docs/essentials/side_effects#going-further-showing-a-spinner--error-handling

Comment: @RémiRousselet: I don't see how to I set the error message in `registerUserWithEmailAndPassword`'s `state` that I can grab from UI. Am I missing something?